# How to break the following line of python

Tags: python, pep8

I have come upon a couple of lines of code similar to this one, but I'm unsure how I should break it:

```
blueprint = Blueprint(self.blueprint_map[str(self.ui.blueprint_combo.currentText())], runs=self.ui.runs_spin.text(), me=self.ui.me_spin.text(), pe=self.ui.pe_skill_combo.currentIndex())
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I find leaving out a parenthesis (or adding an extra) is one good way.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the good answers, the first looks "prettiest" in my eyes, but thanks for the swift reaction!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
blueprint = Blueprint(
    self.blueprint_map[str(self.ui.blueprint_combo.currentText())],
    runs=self.ui.runs_spin.text(), 
    me=self.ui.me_spin.text(),
    pe=self.ui.pe_skill_combo.currentIndex(),
)
```

Answer (score 5):

How about this

```
blueprint_item = self.blueprint_map[str(self.ui.blueprint_combo.currentText())]
blueprint = Blueprint(blueprint_item,
                      runs=self.ui.runs_spin.text(),
                      me=self.ui.me_spin.text(),
                      pe=self.ui.pe_skill_combo.currentIndex())
```

Comment: The intermediate variable name doesn't add any extra information, so in this case I'd be in favour of eliminating it. This could easily be done readably if you didn't indent the args of Blueprint() so much. Keeping the args aligned with the openiong brace like this is common, but misguided because it means if the layout of the first line changes (e.g. by changing the name of 'blueprint') then you need to change the indent on all following lines. Better to use a normal single 4 char indent.

Answer (score 4):

I'd do it this way:

```
blueprint = Blueprint(
              self.blueprint_map[str(self.ui.blueprint_combo.currentText())],
              runs=self.ui.runs_spin.text(),
              me=self.ui.me_spin.text(),
              pe=self.ui.pe_skill_combo.currentIndex())
```

Comment: -1 for the big and arbitrary sized indent. If the layout of the first line changes (e.g. by changing the name of 'blueprint') then you need to change the indent on all following lines. Better to use a normal single 4 char indent.

Answer (score 0):

Anywhere within the brackets should work, such as:

```
blueprint = Blueprint(self.blueprint_map[str(self.ui.blueprint_combo.currentText())],
        runs=self.ui.runs_spin.text(), me=self.ui.me_spin.text(),
        pe=self.ui.pe_skill_combo.currentIndex())
```

Comment: −1: this violates PEP 8 conventions. The hanging indentation is good, but “there should be no arguments on the first line”. Better to break at the opening parenthesis, and align the content of the parens on continuation lines at a consistent 8- (or 4-) column indent.

Answer (score 0):

```
blueprint = Blueprint(self.blueprint_map[str(self.ui.blueprint_combo.currentText())], 
                      runs=self.ui.runs_spin.text(), me=self.ui.me_spin.text(),
                      pe=self.ui.pe_skill_combo.currentIndex())
```

Comment: −1: If you change the length of the first line, the continuation lines would then be mis-aligned. Better to do a single standard indentation level.